# How come I can't see apache's environment variables in my shell?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, apache-2.4

I'm running apache on my Debian 8 laptop. I haven't made any config changes so everything is at the default.

apache2.conf uses environment variable defined in /etc/apache2/envvars, but when I open a shell on my laptop and run printenv I don't see any of those variables defined in envvars.

Are they running in a different context or something? Why can't I see them?

The [apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html) regarding apache environment vars make no mention of envvars so I'm assuming the variables defined there are operating system env vars and are not an apache specific mechanism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are they running in a different context or something?

Yes.

Env vars are not global constants that apply to any process running on a machine. A file containing some env files isn't automatically loaded; Assuming apache uses the file, those env vars are only relevant to when apache is in use, i.e. a http context.

If you want them to be loaded in a shell *you need to load them yourself*, i.e.:

```
$ source /etc/apache2/envvars
$ env # show everything
```

Comment: OK. Also, just so I understand, in the doc I linked to they say Apache also has its own "environmental variables" and that are not the same as OS environment variables. The variables in envvars are OS environment variables and not the internal ones apache uses right?

Comment: the docs for [SetEnvIf](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) may clarify for you. The docs are talking about variables used when evaluating your rules (such as object_is_image).